# POSTGRESQL: remove all characters before a specific character

Tags: postgresql, replace

I have values like `6864#21`, `1a2b#3598` in my database.  I'm trying to extract just the portion before and after the #, so I would get something like

```
col1  | col2
-----------
6864  | 21
1a2b  | 3598
```

I tried

```
REPLACE('123#89', '%#', '')
```

but that just resulted in 123#89.  Does anyone know a way I can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT split_part('123#23','#',1) AS "COL1",split_part('123#23','#',2) AS "COL2"
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use the `strpos` function to find the first occurrence of the character and then `substr` to retrieve everything after that occurrence:

```
SELECT substr(str, strpos(str,'#'));
```

This works if there are multiple `#`'s in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (string_to_array(the_column, '#'))[1] as col1,
       (string_to_array(the_column, '#'))[2] as col2
from the_table
```