# How can get html inner tag in PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have some data like that. And I want to get html.

```
with t(x) as (values( XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT ('<root><NotificationServiceDetails NotificationNo="0" AlarmCode="mail" AlarmStartTime="10:00:00" AlarmTime="0" Id ="2" ><NotificationServiceDetail Id="2"><Title><![CDATA[aaaaaaaaaaaaa]]></Title><ContentJson><![CDATA[
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
      </head>
          <body>
              <table style="font-family: 굴림,맑은 고딕; font-size:12px;color:#333333;border-width: 1px;border-color: #ddd; border-collapse: collapse; margin:5px;width:auto; min-width:600px;">
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" style="border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ddd; background-color: #f5f5f5; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Writer</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Nguyen Ngo Giap (General Mgr.)</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Date</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">2022-01-04 10:00~11:00</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Schedule Div.</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">테스트함</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Content</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Share</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;"></td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </body>
          </html>
            ]]></ContentJson></NotificationServiceDetail></NotificationServiceDetails></root>'))))
    select 
        unnest((xpath('//NotificationServiceDetails/NotificationServiceDetail/@Id',t.x)))::text::integer as Id,
        unnest((xpath('//NotificationServiceDetails/NotificationServiceDetail/Title/text()',t.x))):: text::character varying as Title,
        unnest(xpath('//NotificationServiceDetails/NotificationServiceDetail/ContentJson/text()',t.x))::xml as ContentJson,
        t.x
     from t;
```

but the ContentJson column gives me special characters. "<..." I want the real html

Expect result for column ContentJson.

```
<html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
      </head>
          <body>
              <table style="font-family: 굴림,맑은 고딕; font-size:12px;color:#333333;border-width: 1px;border-color: #ddd; border-collapse: collapse; margin:5px;width:auto; min-width:600px;">
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" style="border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ddd; background-color: #f5f5f5; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Writer</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Nguyen Ngo Giap (General Mgr.)</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Date</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">2022-01-04 10:00~11:00</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Schedule Div.</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">테스트함</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Content</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;">Share</td>
                          <td style="padding: 15px; background-color: #f9f9f9; text-align:left;"></td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </body>
          </html>
```

How can I do that

Comment: What do you mean by "*gives me special characters. `<...`*"?

Comment: Bergi you run it in sql you can see, the result.

Comment: Judging from the [result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=974c68e04d0de6f2e1a997447cb00b08), this is probably a duplicate of [postgresql, xpath query and cdata elements as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028959/postgresql-xpath-query-and-cdata-elements-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 1):

So far, I've provided 5 different solutions - all with their own advantages and problems - you'll have to test on your own data and hardware to ensure that it's working for you!

I did the following (all the relevant code is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=58b3d163d8bdee678f8e7239a20d4cae)):

```
CREATE TABLE t (x TEXT);
```

and populated it with some text similar to yours, but shorter to making testing easier:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
($SOMETAG$with t(x) as (values( XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT ('<root><NotificationServiceDetails NotificationNo="0" AlarmCode="mail" AlarmStartTime="10:00:00" AlarmTime="0" Id ="2" ><NotificationServiceDetail Id="2"><Title><![CDATA[aaaaaaaaaaaaa]]></Title><ContentJson><![CDATA[
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
       </html>
            ]]></ContentJson></NotificationServiceDetail></NotificationServiceDetails></root>'))))
    select 
        unnest((xpath('//NotificationServiceDetails/NotificationServiceDetail/@Id',t.x)))::text::integer as Id,
        unnest((xpath('//NotificationServiceDetails/NotificationServiceDetail/Title/text()',t.x))):: text::character varying as Title,
        unnest(xpath('//NotificationServiceDetails/NotificationServiceDetail/ContentJson/text()',t.x))::xml as ContentJson,
        t.x
     from t;$SOMETAG$);
```

I picked up the `$SOMETAG$`...`$SOMETAG$` technique here - very helpful for insterting characters like single quote (`'`) and backslash (`\`).

There is a "one-pass" solution possible - it justs takes time patience to work it out. Oh, and BTW, there were slight errors in my orininal solution  - since corrected.

### Part 1:

First I remove all characters up to **but** not including `<html lang="en">` as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, STRPOS (x,'<html lang="en"'));
```

[SUBSTRING](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php) and [STRPOS](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/strpos-function.php) were taken from [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55346930/470530).

### Part 2:

Then, I reverse that string using the [`REVERSE()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/reverse-function.php) function

### Part 3:

Finally, I use the SUBSTRING/STRPOS "trick" to chop of the other end of the string to the point of `<ydob>`

### Part 4 is the *pièce de résistance*

I re`REVERSE()` the string to bring it back to its original state - minus the undesirable bits to give the required result.

### 1st Solution (pretty horrible):

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR( REVERSE(SUBSTR(x, strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'))), strpos( REVERSE(SUBSTR(x, strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'))), '>lmth/<'))) FROM t;
```

It looks a bit better (or is more legible at lease):

```
SELECT 
  REVERSE(
    SUBSTR( 
      REVERSE( 
        SUBSTR(x, strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'))), 
          strpos(
            REVERSE(
              SUBSTR(x, strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'))), '>lmth/<'))) FROM t;
```

Instead of these horrible constructions, I used `CTE`'s (Common Table Expressions - AKA the `WITH` CLAUSE to do this [as follows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bec2c04155e5ad735814ada04a85fa57):

Code spends most of its life in maintenance, so easier  to read code is easier to repair.

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(x, strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'))) AS s1 FROM t
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(s1, strpos(s1, 'ydob'))) AS s2 FROM cte1
)
SELECT * from cte2;
```

Result:

```
reverse
<html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
       </html>
```

The answer is the same for all of them!

### 2nd Solution (a bit more elegant - fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=818e3711a4699efda583ea8e1d638084)):

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(x, '</html>', 1) from t;
```

Result:

```
split_part
with t(x) as (values( XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT ('<root><NotificationServiceDetails NotificationNo="0" AlarmCode="mail" AlarmStartTime="10:00:00" AlarmTime="0" Id ="2" ><NotificationServiceDetail Id="2"><Title><![CDATA[aaaaaaaaaaaaa]]></Title><ContentJson><![CDATA[
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
               <<=== Note there are 7 spaces here
```

So, [SPLIT_PART()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-split_part/) cuts the string up to, **but not including** the delimiter - `</html>` in this case. So, using this as follows:

So, we combine two `SPLIT_PART`s in a CTE as follows:

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT LENGTH(split_part(x, '', 1)) AS beg,
LENGTH(split_part(x, '', 1))  AS fin
FROM t
)

Result:

```
substring
 <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
       </html>

-- I cannot understand why I have to add 8 characters to the 408 of the length?
--
-- 7 (the length of </html>) I could possibly get, but why 8?
```

Which is the desired result.

### 3nd Solution (also reasonably elegant - fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5ff90c7081dd3964acd1ab93f25b0c2b)):

I didn't go through all of the steps this time - I combined them all in one query. The interested reader is invited to go through it line by line.

```
SELECT 
  strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'),
  strpos(x, '</html>'),
  strpos(x, '</html>') - strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'),
  substring(x FROM strpos(x, '<html lang="en">') 
    for  ((strpos(x, '</html>') + 8) - strpos(x, '<html lang="en">'))             )
FROM t; 

--
-- Again, I'm puzzled by the necessity to use 8 characters.
--
--
```

Result:

```
strpos  strpos  ?column?    substring
265     409     144     <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Et voilà - the desired result!

### 4th Solution (a bit convoluted, but may be instructive - fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5354bcd81ce77d3171126650afae7f4)):

### 1st Step:

I split the lines into records in a table as follows:

```
SELECT 
  x.idx,
  LENGTH(x.string),
  x.string
FROM t,
  REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.x, '\n') WITH ORDINALITY AS x(string, idx);
```

### 2nd step:

I pull out the records I want which correspond to the desired result as follows:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT 
    x.idx,
    LENGTH(x.string) AS ls,
    x.string
  FROM t,
    REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.x, '\n') WITH ORDINALITY AS x(string, idx)
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT idx, ls, string 
  FROM cte1
  WHERE string ~ '<html lang="en">' OR string ~ '</html>'
  ORDER BY idx
)
SELECT idx, ls, string
FROM cte1
WHERE idx BETWEEN 
  (SELECT MIN(idx) FROM cte2) AND (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM cte2);
```

Result:

```
idx     ls  string
2   22        <html lang="en">
3   12        <head>
4   33            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
5   20            more stuff
6   20            more stuff
7   16          </table>
8   13        </body>
9   14         </html>
```

As you can see, the string field contains the data we want!

### Solution 5 - using a relatively simple regular expression - fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=28666e8a09919e8bc345cbb77faa993a)

1st pass:

We check the output of the very handy `PG_TYPEOF()` function, which from the docco [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-info.html) does:

> pg_typeof returns the OID of the data type of the value that is passed
> to it. This can be helpful for troubleshooting or dynamically
> constructing SQL queries. The function is declared as returning
> regtype, which is an OID alias type (see Section 8.18); this means
> that it is the same as an OID for comparison purposes but displays as
> a type name.

So, our first query is:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_MATCH(x, '^.*(<head>.*</html>).*'), 
  PG_TYPEOF(REGEXP_MATCH(x, '^.*(<head>.*</html>).*'))
  FROM t;
```

Result:

```
regexp_match                          pg_typeof
{"<head>
          <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
       </html>"}                       text[]
```

So, we have our data, but it's surrounded by braces (curly brackets) - but we know from our `PG_TYPEOF()` function is a text array, so we know that it's the first (only) element of that array, so therefore we can use the array element notation as follows:

```
SELECT 
  (REGEXP_MATCHES(x, '^.*(<head>.*</html>).*'))[1]  -- <<-- Note [1]
  FROM t;
```

Result:

```
regexp_matches
<head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          more stuff
          more stuff
        </table>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Same as the others!
Which is the same as for the others!

### Crude performance analysis

After 5 runs, the order of merit appears to be the following (a fiddle of the tests run may be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01363293d220f4ea8e0974c6146a85b2). Times will vary according to other uses to which the server may be being put, but as I said, I found them to be fairly consistent in terms of time and always in the same order on the 5 runs that I examined.

In descending order of run time:

- 1st) **Method 3**: [STRPOS()](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/strpos-function.php)  Time  ~ 0.045ms: - let that be a base of 1 times fastest execution
- 2nd) **Method 1** [SUBSTRING()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-substring/) & [REVERSE()](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/strpos-function.php) 0.079ms: x times **1.75**
- 3rd) **Method 2**: [SPLIT_PART()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-split_part/)                          x times **2.25**
- 4th) **Method 4**: [REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE()](https://pgpedia.info/r/regexp_split_to_table.html#:%7E:text=regexp_split_to_table()%20is%20a%20system,was%20added%20in%20PostgreSQL%208.3.) WITH CTE     x times **13.2**
- 5th **Method 5**: [REGEXP_MATCH()](https://pgpedia.info/r/regexp_split_to_table.html#:%7E:text=regexp_split_to_table()%20is%20a%20system,was%20added%20in%20PostgreSQL%208.3.) x times **49.4**

So, we can see that the most expensive algorithm is ~ 50 times more expensive than the most efficient one. The usual caveats about benchmarking with only one record **and** on an unknown system apply - although the results where fairly consistent over at least 5 runs. **Always** benchmark on your own system with your own data!